# how to convert opencv image(8UC3) to a char * array

Tags: opencv

I have a RGB image. I load it in opencv using:

```
Mat image;
image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file
```

Now I need to create an uchar *array from the image data.
How do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uchar* cv::Mat::data

pointer to the data
```

And don't forget that `Mat` actual row size might differ from width*sizeof(element):

```
 cv::Mat::step is needed because the matrix can be a part of another matrix
 or because there can some padding space in the end of each row for a proper 
 alignment.
```